# Full Calender display listview day-slot start and end time instead of all-day

Tags: javascript, php, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I want to display events in calender between two days for specific time like

```
ABC: 2/11/2020 - 2/15/2020 (for time 02:00:00 to 03:00:00)
DEF: 2/11/2020 - 2/15/2020 (for time 02:00:00 to 05:00:00)
EFG: 2/12/2020 - 2/17/2020 (for time 02:00:00 to 03:00:00)
```

The calendar list view it display time with class **fc-list-item-time** which by default is all-day i search for solution but cant find it. i tried following script which doesnt meet my current requirment.
the calender initialization event parameter looks like

```
events: [
   // ---------------- php loop over this for above entires ---------------
  {
   title: 'abc',
   start: '2020-2-11 02:00:00',   
   description: 'Reservation By Dummy',
   end: '2020-02-15 03:00:00',  
// ------------------- these also doesnt give me desired result -------------------
//   setStart:"",
//   minTime:"",
// recurstart:"",
// recurend:"",
// ranges:[{start:"02:00:00", end:"03:00:00"}],
//  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   className: "fc-event-success"
   },
        // ---------------- php loop over this for above entires ---------------
                    ],
```

When i use time also with the start parameter directly and end one *(just like example above)* then it display **all-day** for all days except last day and on last day it show the end time.

[image]

i want it to be displayed like

[image]

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/recurring-events is probably what you need to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it

```
    events: [
   // ---------------- php loop over this for above entires ---------------
  {
   title: 'abc',
   start: '2020-2-11',   
   description: 'Reservation By Dummy',
   end: '2020-02-15',  
   mycustomparameter1: '02:00:00',
   mycustomparameter2: '03:00:00',
   className: "fc-event-success"
   },
        // ---------------- php loop over this for above entires ---------------
                    ],
```

i solve with help of **eventRender** function

```
eventRender: function (info) {
var element = $(info.el);
 if (info.event.extendedProps) {
   if (element.find('.fc-list-item-time').lenght !== 0) {
       element.find('.fc-list-item-time').html(info.event.extendedProps.mycustomparameter1+'-'+info.event.extendedProps.mycustomparameter2); 
                        
   }
 }
```